# Cannot hide layers in QField

Tags: qfield

When I press a layer name and select "hide layer" in QField nothing happens, the layer won't hide. I've had experienced it with some layers but not with others. Then I am lost.

Comment: what device are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab S4

Comment: well, It worked now. issue solved.